# What is a good KDE equivalent to gnome-do?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, kde, gnome-do

I'd like it to be seamless in regard to performance.

Here's how I use [gnome-do](http://do.davebsd.com)

by hitting <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> I get a prompt and I start typing, it starts showing me programs to run using the characters I am typing, if it's what I want I can hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> or I can use the down-arrow to scroll to other possible matches.

There is much more to gnome-do, but I'm still just a basic launcher user. The key for me is the ability to start typing and launch any app. No More Mouse.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would imagine it redundant to name it something under KDE4.

The behaviour I ascribe to Gnome-Do ( I haven't really used it, I'm just going by what I see on Gnome-Do's website ) is part of Kde's implicit functionality now.

Just start typing in the search field that's on the menu, or start typing in the run dialogue ( Default shortcut is  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> )

For an example of what It can do:

> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> , <kbd>f</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>e</kbd>

Yeilds in the list

1. Edit - Mozilla Firefox ( Activate Running Window on Desktop 1 )
2. Mozilla Firefox ( Web Browser )

Which I can switch between with <kbd>Tab</kbd> and execute with <kbd>Enter</kbd>

You can run any command there you could run in a shell too,

> trigger: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
>   command: [xhost +]
>   shows: *Run xhost +*
>   launch: <kbd>Enter</kbd>

As well as running commands in a shell

> trigger: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
>   command: [ ls ]
>   shows: *Run ls*
>   navigate to execute option: <kbd>Tab</kbd>
>   open configuration instead: <kbd>Space</kbd>
>   navigate to 'run in termainal' option: <kbd>Tab</kbd>
>   toggle checkbox: <kbd>Space</kbd>
>   launch: <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Doing basic math:

> trigger: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
>   command: [1 + 1 =]
>   shows: *2*

Spell checking:

> trigger: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
>   command: spell frabujous
>   shows: *list of spellings*

Open Web Searches:

> trigger: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
>   command: wp: duck
>   shows: *Search Wikipedia for duck*
>   launch: <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Launch Apps by Description:

> trigger: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
>   command: web browser
>   shows: *list of applications that are web browsers*
>   select one: <kbd>Tab</kbd>
>   launch: <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Do all sorts of web browsery things:

> trigger: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
>   command: stack
>   shows:
>
> - Stack Overflow - Konqueror ( Activate Window Running on Desktop 1 )
> - `<history>` stackoverflow.com /
> - `<bookmark>` Stack Overflow
>
> select one: <kbd>Tab</kbd>
>   launch: <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Filesystem Browsing:

> trigger: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
>   command: /tmp/
>   shows: *Open /tmp/*
>   launch: <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Do Power Controls:

> trigger: <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
>   command: suspend
>   shows: *Suspend To Ram*
>   launch: <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Its only really limited by how complete your data is and what plug-ins you have.

Comment: gotcha, will update my question with more info to be more specific.

Comment: very well expounding out that detail! and yesterday this is what I chose to use, not sure if I'll stick with KDE or not, but it's fun messing around.

Comment: Great summary. The only thing that comes to my mind that you forget was desktop search. By entering any keywords it can also show the found documents.

Comment: I only put things up that I could test myself and assured work. I don't use desktop search because the dependencies and overheads incurred from the neopmuk/akonadi duo ( with database et all ) make my life too interesting, and I never find a need to use it anyway =). for compare, 'locate' is often annoying enough to me that I totally disable the cron job.

Answer (score 8):

For KDE4:
Gnome-Do = [KRunner](http://userbase.kde.org/Tutorials/Krunner) (built-in, hit Alt-F2)

For KDE3:
Gnome-Do = [Katapult](http://katapult.kde.org/)

Comment: is KRunner any more useful than the gnome-launcher built in with gnome? and maybe that had more features than I used it for.... gnome-do was just more helpful it seemed.

Comment: Also, this thread with subject "KDE Do?" -- http://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=12147

Comment: KRunner is pretty powerful, it does suggestions and can do magic suff like   'spell frablous' will instantly show ( while you type it ) alternative spellings, '7 + 7 =' will show '14' as  soon as you type '=', amongst other things, its only limited by its plugins.

Answer (score 2):

Gnome do works just as well in KDE as in GNOME.

From [Do's homepage](http://do.davebsd.com/):

> Do is just as sleek, swift and smart on KDE and other common environments.

Since you're on Ubuntu, you can install it with this command:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-do
```

Answer (score 1):

It is called [Katapult](http://katapult.kde.org/) and works very similar but has not a Docky like skin. Personally I love gnome-do so I - of course - have to mention the [wiki entry](http://do.davebsd.com/wiki/KDE_Users) saying that it will work under KDE as well.

Comment: nice, I don't really use docky, but I will have to check out the KDE support for do, wonder if it has performance issues since it's not written specific for KDE... Will read.

Answer (score 1):

[Synapse](https://launchpad.net/synapse-project) - it's in the Ubuntu repositories. [image: Install synapse]

[image]

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> - <kbd>Space</kbd> to start typing.

[More details](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/11/synapse-gnome-do-launcher-app-review-ubuntu).